# use a local component variable in another component without using selector

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a component in angular named `first_component`. I'm using another component named `second_component` in its HTML like:

```
<second_component [addChildMode]='addChildMode' [defaultValues]='defaultValues' [chosenRelationIsInitialRelation]='chosenRelationIsInitialRelation'></second_component>
```

As you see, I'm passing some values from first_component to second_component such as `addChildMode`, `defaultValues` etc. using `@Input()`.
(Since I'm using second_component with selector, I can use `@Input()`).
Now I have a `showValue` which is a local variable in second_component and I want to be aware of its change! Since I'm not using first_component by its selector, how can I notice when `showValue` is changed in second component?
P.s. first_component and second_component are just siblings. (Not child and parent)

Comment: It's not really clear but can't you use `@Output` to expose the "local variable of second component" changes?

Comment: @GaëlJ No, because `showValue` is not an output method. it's a local variable inside `second_component`

Comment: There's no way to listen to a local variable from a component if it's not an `Output` or if it's not actually a variable from a shared service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to react to changes in `showValue` across multiple components, it is **not** (shouldn't be) **local** anymore. If you use NgRX or similar state management, you can put `showValue` in a store. I recommend this *only* if that variable has a global bearing.

But since it sounds more like couple components working closely together in a more or less local setting, I recommend using a shared service which will hold the `showValue`'s value in a an observable to which these 2 components can push/subscribe.

Answer (score -2):

My suggestion would be using ChangeDetectionStrategy, that too if not that necessary or if you do not have any other way.

Using state management would be good for a large project, but would make application heavy if used in smaller projects.

Comment: ChangeDetectionStrategy has nothing to do with the problem in question.